# Angular Mask | Input value replace when left and right arrow press

Tags: angularjs, mask

Click leftward and rightward in the input, it will replace the value instead of shifting the value.

For eg: 12.34.56

when i moving the cursor to 1 and replacing this value with 7. It shows 71.23.45
but i want to replace the 1 with 7 i.e. 72.34.56

Comment: Without some code, it is really difficult to  understand what is happening and why it is happening

Comment: I am using the angular mask - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask

Comment: Refer this - https://plnkr.co/edit/zZbSnfiLRH4ssqE5ms17?p=preview